# How to check if three columns have similar like value in Excel

Tags: r, excel, vba

I have below mentioned excel sheet.

```
ID  column1    column2     column3
1   Apple      apple - x   Apple - le
2   Mango      banana      cat
3   Dog        DOG - A     DOG - B
```

I want to match string of column1, column2 and column3 (where atlease one word is similar in these three column).

Required Output:

```
ID  column1    column2     column3     Status
1   Apple      apple - x   Apple - le  True
2   Mango      banana      cat         False
3   Dog        DOG - A     DOG - B     True
```

Comment: I wonder why this question was upvoted. The OP does not show any research on his own at all.

Answer (score 2):

Code for **LO BO**'s idea.

In Excel with *VBA*, try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function ThreeWay(s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String) As Boolean
    Dim a As String, b As String, c As String

    a = Split(s1, " ")(0)
    b = Split(s2, " ")(0)
    c = Split(s3, " ")(0)
    ThreeWay = False
    If a = b And a = c Then ThreeWay = True
End Function
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

For only two columns, use:

```
Public Function TwoWay(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Boolean
    Dim a As String, b As String, c As String

    a = Split(s1, " ")(0)
    b = Split(s2, " ")(0)
    TwoWay = False
    If a = b Then TwoWay = True
End Function
```

**EDIT#2:**

To ignore case differences, try:

```
Public Function ThreeWayIC(s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String) As Boolean
    Dim a As String, b As String, c As String

    a = Split(UCase(s1), " ")(0)
    b = Split(UCase(s2), " ")(0)
    c = Split(UCase(s3), " ")(0)
    ThreeWayIC = False
    If a = b And a = c Then ThreeWayIC = True
End Function
```

Comment: How to run this VBA only for 2 columns, where should i made the change in the code.

Comment: @Gray's Student It is not working for string like if column1 is `Abc-Xyz` and column2 is `ABC Xve`

Comment: Of course not and I would recommend to do some own research, i.e. look at StrComp

Comment: @Rahulshah  Do you want the code to **ignore** case differences or **honor** them??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I want to ignore the case differences.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent It's not working for those where string is like `Abc-Xyx` and `ABC xVc` and `C - ABCD` and `ABCD`. the code should match the see the similar word in two columns and give the value `True`.

Comment: @Rahulshah I do not understand.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent The code should math any one word and show result as true or maximum length of word is matching in both the column than result would be true.

Comment: @Rahulshah  I think I understand.............Sadly my code only considers the **first** word in each cell.............. *(just as in your question)*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent My bad i think i couldn't explain the exact requirement..(

Comment: @Rahulshah I strongly encourage you to modify the original question.  We may get a better answer!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in base R?

```
lst1 <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$column2), " - "), function(x)
    trimws(tolower(x)));
lst2 <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$column3), " - "), function(x)
    trimws(tolower(x)));

df$Status <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i)
    any(lst1[[i]] %in% lst2[[i]]));
df;
#  ID column1   column2    column3 Status
#1  1   Apple apple - x Apple - le   TRUE
#2  2   Mango    banana        cat  FALSE
#3  3     Dog   DOG - A    DOG - B   TRUE
```

Explanation: Split entries in `column2` and `column3` based on `" - "`, trim any whitespace and convert all terms to lower case; then check if `any` terms are present in `column2` and `column3`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "ID  column1    column2     column3
1   Apple      'apple - x'   'Apple - le'
2   Mango      'banana'      cat
3   Dog        'DOG - A'     'DOG - B'", header = T);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you get the first word of the cell using the [Split function](http://www.excelfunctions.net/split-string-in-excel.html) (see "Return Text From the Beginning of a Text String, Up to the First Space") and then count the number of matches using the [COUNTIF function](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/90855-formula-check-if-3-cells-have-identical-value.html).