# Check if columns have similar like value in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have below mentioned excel sheet:

```
ID  column1    column2     column3
1   Apple X    apple - x   Apple - le
2   Mango Y    banana      cat
3   Dog        DOG - A     DOG - B
4   L-Lion     Lion        Lion- Cd
```

I want to check if three of these column have any word (or Maximum length of word) similar like other two columns.

I want to ignore the case difference here.

I have below mentioned VBA code for this but it couldn't give me the required output.

```
Public Function Test(s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String) As Boolean
    Dim a As String, b As String, c As String

    a = Split(UCase(s1), " ")(0)
    b = Split(UCase(s2), " ")(0)

    Test= False
    If a = b And a = c Then ThreeWayIC = True
End Function
```

Required Output:

```
ID  column1    column2     column3     Status
1   Apple X    apple - x   Apple - le  True
2   Mango Y    banana      cat         False
3   Dog        DOG - A     DOG - B     True
4   L-Lion     Lion        Lion- Cd    True
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192604/how-to-check-if-three-columns-have-similar-like-value-in-excel Isn't this the same question?

Comment: @Storax Yes i have tried to recreate it.

Comment: And what else did you besides copying the function from the other thread wrongly (you changed the name of the function to test but did not change it in the function itself completely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following function but be aware it is not working for your fourth line because you consider L-LION as two words but the function will consider it as one word. Either you add spaces or think about a unique delimiter. You might also extend the function for a second delimiter like a  dash.

```
Function isContained(ByVal s1 As String, ByVal s2 As String, ByVal s3 As String) As Boolean

Const BLANK = " "

Dim a As Variant

    a = Split(UCase(s1), BLANK)
    isContained = False

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If InStr(1, s2, a(i), vbTextCompare) >= 1 And InStr(1, s3, a(i), vbTextCompare) >= 1 Then isContained = True
    Next i

End Function
```

**EDIT** I added the dash just "quick and dirty"

```
Function isContained(ByVal s1 As String, ByVal s2 As String, ByVal s3 As String) As Boolean

Const BLANK = " "
Const DASH = "-"

Dim a As Variant

    a = Split(UCase(s1), BLANK)
    isContained = False

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If InStr(1, s2, a(i), vbTextCompare) >= 1 And InStr(1, s3, a(i), vbTextCompare) >= 1 Then isContained = True
    Next i

    a = Split(UCase(s1), DASH)
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If InStr(1, s2, a(i), vbTextCompare) >= 1 And InStr(1, s3, a(i), vbTextCompare) >= 1 Then isContained = True
    Next i


End Function
```

Comment: Thank You...con you suggest me based on column where should i tweak in the code. (i.e if i want to run the same on 4,5,6 columns or just 2 colums)

Comment: Could you plese tell me if the code works for the original question?

Comment: Then I would suggest to close this thread, try something on your own and in case you get stuck create a new question with reference to this one.